# Is it possible to access file in xap in desktop application

Tags: wpf, winforms

Is it possible to access or get file list in xap file through desktop application.If possible please let me know how to do this.

Thanks
Dinesh

Answer (score 2):

XAPs [are just ZIP files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAP_%28file_format%29).

You can use any ZIP library, such as the [`ZipArchive` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) in .Net 4.5.